# how to add new line in msg when notification send form php script?

Tags: php, android, string, newline

while sending notification from php to android phone how to add new line in msg?

Below is code than i am trying to send it will print \n in android notification.
I have also used a 
 instead of \n in below msg  but it shows HTML Tags i

```
$msg = 'Your Leave Application \n \n


                                   Employee Code :'.$user_data["emp_code"].' \n
                                   Employee Name :'.$user_data["full_name"].' \n
                                   Employee Email:'.$user_data["user_name"].' \n
                                   Type of Leave :'.$type.' \n
                                   No. of Days   :'.$days.' \n
                                   From date     :'.$from_date.' \n
                                   To Date       :'.$to_date.' \n
                                   Reason        :'.$reason;
```

Comment: Try using double quoted string. That will convert `\n` to a newline properly. `$msg = "Your Leave Application\n\n"....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Escape sequences are ignored in single quotes strings in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). You need to use double quoted strings.

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.
>
> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.